# ssrs url path string manipulation

Tags: reporting-services

I have a url string that I'm getting from the DB for a file in my sharepoint server e.g.

http://mysharepointserver.com/abc/def.jpg

and I would like to get the url path e.g. http://mysharepointserver.com/abc removing the file name. Can someone please give me an example on how this can be done in SSRS? I'm using SSRS 2012 but I'm fairly new to SSRS.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Vince.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write some custom code on the report. There is a Code property on the report itself where you can write VB functions. One similar to this should do the job.

```
Function GetPath(ByVal FullPath As String) As String
  Return System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(FullPath)
End Function
```

Then in the expression on a Textbox you can call the function.

```
=Code.GetPath("http://mysharepointserver.com/abc/def.jpg")
```

For more detailed step by step instructions try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx

Comment: Thanks for help on how to add the custom code, Path.GetDirectoryName is not really used for URL as it incorrectly converts the / to \ This is the custom code I used: Public Shared Function GetFullyQualifiedURL(url As String) As String
 Dim opResult As String = url
 Dim pos As Integer = url.LastIndexOf("/"C)
 If pos > 0 Then
  opResult = url.Substring(0, pos)
 End If
 Return opResult
End Function

Comment: Fair point. The function was off the top of my head, but glad it was enough to point you to a working solution.