# Decode Bracket in SSRS URL

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-lightswitch, urldecode, html-escape-characters

I'm totally stuck.

Some background.  I have an SSRS report which displays some info.  I have also built a LightSwitch HTML application which allows a user to edit that same info.  The goal is to allow users to directly navigate to an edit screen from within the SSRS report.

> My end result would be `http://Server.Company.net/TimeLogs_LS/HTMLClient/#/ViewRecordDetails/79456/[c1e469bee]`
>   (a URL which I know works)
>
> Which I am attempting to achieve within the `Go To URL Action` value of a String's `TextProperties` in SSRS using the following code: `="http://cmbapp1.brattle.net/TimeLogs_LS/HTMLClient/#/ViewRecordDetails/" & Fields!ProjectCommentKeySK.Value & "/[c1e469bee]"`
>
> The Problem I'm having is that `[c1e469bee]` keeps escaping to `%5Bc1e469bee%5D`

I have tried to follow the `Decode` technique outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334131/ssrs-url-path-string-manipulation) and have tried implementing `unescape()` which I later saw is deprecated.

All help would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally, any suggestions about how to link to specific LightSwitch records would be nice, but I've looked into DeepLinking  / URL parameters with no luck.
And I have found very little discussing the URL's unique ID generation, without which the program 'breaks'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy for the deep link to navigate to a 'View Details Screen' you could use the 'Default Details Screen' approach outlined in the following MSDN blog (see the example towards the end):

[New Navigation Features in LightSwitch HTML Client (Chris Rummel, Rohit Agrawal)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2013/11/07/new-navigation-features-in-lightswitch-html-client-chris-rummel-rohit-agrawal.aspx)

This type of view screen will need to be set to 'Browse' to allow it to be used as the default details screen for the entity type.

Whilst this means that you'll need to implement an edit button on the view screen, it will allow you to use a deep link url with the following structure:

`{your_base_url}?entity={data_source_name}/{entity_collection_name}({entity_id})`

For example:

`http://localhost:38202?entity=NorthwindEntitiesData/Customers(1234)`

We're in the process of testing this technique in the LightSwitch HTML Client alongside rdlc reports rendered in [Syncfusion's Report Viewer](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/lightswitchhtml/ejreportviewer).

Like you we're using the "Go to URL" action, which is successfully deep linking using the above technique with the following type of hyperlink expression in our rdlc report:

```
=string.Format("http://localhost:38202?entity=NorthwindEntitiesData/Customers({0})",Fields!Id.Value)
```

Whilst we're not using SSRS to manage and view our reports, I'd still expect the above to work for you in SSRS and with rdl as opposed to rdlc report files.

Comment: Thank you that method worked perfectly.  Although I still can't decode the brackets I can move forward with development, thank you!